# Meteor.users.update access denied when adding a new field to current document in collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-accounts, mongodb-update

I'm looking to add a new field (array that will be populated with $push in the future) to the current document but am getting the error `update failed: MongoError: Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array`

I'm working on the Meteor.users collection.

The code ran was:

```
var user = Meteor.userId();
Meteor.users.update({_id:user}, {$set: {"newfield": ["some data"]}});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you're not supposed to change the root fields of the user object. From [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users):

> By default, the current user's `username`, `emails` and `profile` are published to the client. You can publish additional fields with [...]

So you can

```
Meteor.users.update(user, {$set: {"profile.newfield": ["some data"]}});
```

Note though that you should [limit](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) what you [store in `profile`](http://joshowens.me/the-curious-case-of-the-unknowing-leaky-meteor-security/).

Comment: This may not be the best advice if [you want it to sync](https://medium.com/@MaxDubrovin/workaround-for-meteor-limitations-if-you-want-to-sub-for-more-nested-fields-of-already-received-docs-eb3fdbfe4e07)

Answer (score 1):

You need to define "newfield" as an array or the operation will fail. See here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push